# Python Dataframe: Find if Column Value is in List Variables and Label Accordingly

Tags: python, list, pandas, dataframe, matching

1) I have a list variable called weekday_list that is comprised of string words separated by commas
example: `weekday_list = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday']`

2) I also have another similar list variable called weekend_list
example: `weekend_list = ['Saturday', 'Sunday']`

Let's say I have the following dataframe:

```
Date    Day_of_Week            
1/5     Monday           
1/6     Tuesday          
1/7     Wednesday   
1/8     Thursday    
1/9     Friday   
1/10    Saturday    
1/11    Sunday
```

I want to do the following with Python code:

a) Create a new column called "Label" that says 'weekday' if the value in column "Day_of_Week" is in the variable weekday_list

b) says "weekend" if the value in column "Day_of_Week" is in the variable weekend_list

c) finally says NA if the value in column "Day_of_Week" is in neither variable

*Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using `pandas`, there are a few different ways to do this. Here is an intuitive option. The way it works: use the `.isin()` method to create a logical index to indicate if the *Day_of_Week* is in the *weekday_list* or *weekend_list* or neither, and then update the *Label* column accordingly with `.loc` accessor:

```
import numpy as np
df["Label"] = np.nan
df.loc[df.Day_of_Week.isin(weekday_list), "Label"] = "weekday"
df.loc[df.Day_of_Week.isin(weekend_list), "Label"] = "weekend"
```

[image]

---

Another one-liner option would be to use `np.where`:

```
df["Label"] = np.where(df.Day_of_Week.isin(weekday_list), "weekday", 
                       np.where(df.Day_of_Week.isin(weekend_list), "weekend", 
                                None))
```

Answer (score 1):

you can create a `label_dict` instead and use `pd.Series.map`

```
label_dict = {}
for wd in weekday_list:
    label_dict[wd] = 'weekday'
for we in weekend_list:
    label_dict[we] = 'weekend'

df.Day_of_Week.map(label_dict)

0    weekday
1    weekday
2    weekday
3        NaN
4        NaN
5    weekend
6    weekend
Name: Day_of_Week, dtype: object
```